# Hay alguna mejor manera de agregar una imagen y su descripción que no sea con ImageView y TextView?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con android studio y quiero practicar con esta actividad y lo que quiero lograr es agregar una imagen con una pequeña descripción de la misma pero quería saber si solamente se puede hacer usando los componentes `ImageView` y `TextView` o hay alguna mejor manera de hacerlo, y como puedo agregar una Scrollbar para poder ver todas las imágenes y descripciones que coloque por que si van a ser varias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A esto le quiero aplicar una scrollbar desde donde dice "unidad central de educación" hasta donde dice "El Municipio se encuentra localizado"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Usa [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView) y [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView), es mucho mas ordenado a la hora de trabajar, no tienes que crear todos esos `ImageView` y `TextView`, sino que solo creas un `CardView` con imagen y texto, luego con un `RecyclerView` lo llenas con los contenidos que desees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre usa los componentes correctos ya que cada uno tienen sus diferentes atributos y cada uno te ayuda en diferentes formas. si quieres una imagen puedes usar ImageView, TextView, puedes poner una imagen hasta en un boton,EditText pero en forma de background. 
Para poder usar un scroll view lo arrastras y lo pones hasta arriba de donde quieres que empiece, el scroll view por defecto te pone el LinearLayout pero tu puedes llamar el layout que gustes.
Ejemplo en xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".Ejemplo">

   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  <---Ejemplo
            android:text="Ejemplo" />

      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```